# MySQL 'tahun_pemilihan' in where clause is ambigous

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1052

How can I correct the problem I keep getting from the code below which states 'tahun_pemilihan' in where the clause is ambiguous. Thanks for the help in advance.

here is the MySQL table

```
 $sql = "SELECT 
              a.*, b.vektor_v FROM data_alternatif a, hasil b 
    WHERE a.id_alternatif=b.id_alternatif AND tahun_pemilihan='$thn'";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both tables contain a column named `tahun_pemilihan` so in the `WHERE` clause condition it is not clear which table's column to use; should it use the one from `data_alternatif` or from the results table `hasil`?

Qualify the table in the `WHERE` clause with either `a.tahun_pemilihan='$thn'`  if it should use column `data_alternatif.tahun_pemilihan` or `b.tahun_pemilihan='$thn'` if `hasil.tahun_pemilihan` is the one to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can encounter ambiguous column name error if the column name exist in both tables you have joined.

In your case, the column name `tahun_pemilihan` exist in both of your table.

Solution:

Pick which one of the two table you will use.
`a.tahun_pemilihan='$thn'` or `b.tahun_pemilihan='$thn'`

https://www.quora.com/What-does-the-SQL-ambiguous-column-name-error-mean